# How to fetch records without Duplicates using Linq

Tags: c#, json, linq, .net-core

Hi can someone assist please,i have a list that contain my promotions codes and in the list i would like to return only promotion codes that appear once i.e dont have duplicates,please see below data from JSON,i would like to return Promotion code A123 and B500 and store them in another list.

```
[
   {
    "PromCode": "A123",
    "Priority": 1,
    "offer": "Win a Free Cap",
    "StartDte": "2020-08-11T00:16:23.184Z",
    "endDte": "2020-09-10T17:16:23.184Z",
  }, 
  {
    "PromCode": "A100",
    "Priority": 1,
    "offer": "Win a perfume",
    "StartDte": "2020-08-11T00:16:23.184Z",
    "endDte": "2020-09-10T17:16:23.184Z",
  },
{
    "PromCode": "A100",
    "Priority": 2,
    "offer": "Win a Phone pouch",
    "StartDte": "2020-09-11T00:16:23.184Z",
    "endDte": "2020-10-10T17:16:23.184Z",
  },
 {
    "PromCode": "B500",
    "Priority": 1,
    "offer": "Win a free router",
    "StartDte": "2020-08-11T00:16:23.184Z",
    "endDte": "2020-09-10T17:16:23.184Z",
  },

]
```

I have a list that contains all this promotion code as seen below

```
var existingProms = await _Repo.GetAllPromCodes(promCodeList);
```

i tried to get ones that appear once in the list like this

```
var appearOnce = existingProms.Count(x => existingBnplIndicators.Contains(x.PromCode)).ToList()<2;
var appearOnce = existingProms.where(x=> x.PromCode.Count()).ToList()<2;
```

But this did not work,there is 0 results returned,could someone show how to get my two Proms A123,B500 into my appearOnce lis.Thankst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` to get all the results grouped by PromoCode. Then, filter the results based on the number of items each group has to only show when `Count() == 1`.

Something like this perhaps,

```
public class Class1
{
    public string PromCode { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public string offer { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDte { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDte { get; set; }
}

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(json);
var singlesOnly = obj.GroupBy(x => x.PromCode).Where(y => y.Count() == 1);
```

Comment: @Jawas Thank you that worked,just needed to add var singlesOnly = obj.GroupBy(x => x.PromCode).Where(y => y.Count() == 1). Select(x=>x.Key.ToString()).ToList(); for it to return the singlessOnly as list of strings

Answer (score 0):

You should compare desired objects only by promcode implicitly. Take look how Equals and GetHashCode() works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace test
{
    public class TestObj : IEquatable<TestObj>
    {
        public string Promocode { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public string offer { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
        public override int GetHashCode() => this.Promocode.GetHashCode();
        public bool Equals(TestObj other) => Promocode.Equals(other.Promocode);
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new TestObj()
            {
                Promocode = "1",
                Priority = 1,
                offer = "1",
                StartDate = new DateTime(1, 2, 3),
                endDate = new DateTime(1, 2, 3)
            };

            var b = new TestObj()
            {
                Promocode = "1",
                Priority = 1,
                offer = "1",
                StartDate = new DateTime(1, 2, 3),
                endDate = new DateTime(1, 2, 3)
            };
            var c = new TestObj()
            {
                Promocode = "2",
                Priority = 1,
                offer = "1",
                StartDate = new DateTime(1, 2, 3),
                endDate = new DateTime(1, 2, 3)
            };

            var list = new List<TestObj>()
            {
                a,
                b,
                c
            };

            var uniqueOnly = list.Distinct();

            foreach (var item in uniqueOnly)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Promocode);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First define class items-

```
        public string PromCode { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public string offer { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDte { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDte { get; set; }
```

Then take multiple items in list and use distinct() function to remove duplicate values-

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TestClass> list = new List<TestClass>()
        {
            new TestClass(){PromCode="A123",Priority=1,offer="Win a Free 
            Cap",StartDte=new DateTime(2020-08-11),endDte=new DateTime(2020-09-10)},

            new TestClass(){PromCode="A100",Priority=1,offer="Win a 
            perfume",StartDte=new DateTime(2020-08-11),endDte=new DateTime(2020-09- 
            10)},

            new TestClass(){PromCode="A100",Priority=2,offer="Win a Phone 
            pouch",StartDte=new DateTime(2020-09-11),endDte=new DateTime(2020-10-10)},

            new TestClass(){PromCode="B500",Priority=1,offer="Win a free 
            router",StartDte=new DateTime(2020-08-11),endDte=new DateTime(2020-09-10)}
        };

        var finalList = list.Select(b => b.PromCode).Distinct().ToList();
        foreach(var item in finalList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item + "");
        }
        Console.Read();
        }
    }
```